# Question about rearranging terms of a sequence in limit superior.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $a_n$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers and $\phi: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ a bijection.

Is it true that:
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n-a_{\phi(n)})=0 $$

And for that matter does
$\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n = \limsup_{n\to \infty}a_{\phi(n)} $?

Unable to find a counterexample, I tried to prove this by somehow showing that $|\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n-a_{\phi(n)})|\leq 0$.

Using basic properties I get:
\begin{array} 
|\limsup_{n\to \infty} (a_n-a_{\phi(n)})| 
& \leq |\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to \infty}-a_{\phi(n)}| \\
& \leq |\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n - \liminf_{n\to \infty}a_{\phi(n)}| \\
\end{array}

Which in my mind sums up to showing that the sequence
$a_n-a_{\phi(n)}$ converges. I figured that this is not true since for the sequence $0,1,0,1 \dots$ I can rearrange it as $0,0,1,0,0,1 \dots$ and so the difference of the two is still divergent.

What is the right approach to tackle this type of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n$, and let

$$\varphi(n)=\begin{cases}
n+1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
n-1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd,}
\end{cases}$$

so that

$$\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle 1,-1,1,-1,\ldots\rangle\,,$$

and

$$\langle a_{\varphi(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle -1,1,-1,1,\ldots\rangle\,.$$

Then

$$\langle a_n-a_{\varphi(n)}:\in\Bbb N\rangle=\langle 2,-2,2,-2,\ldots\rangle=\langle 2(-1)^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\,,$$

with limit superior $2$.